# Console says cannot read property "style" of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am making slider using `carousel` from `w3schools.com`. It is working fine in the desired page. But when I want to move another page it says `cannot read property "style" of undefined`

Here is my script file.

```
var slideIndex = 0;

function slider() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slider");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";  //***problem is here***
    setTimeout(slider, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
}
//end script for home page slider
```

Here is my div section code:

```
<div class="slider-image" onload="slider()">
    <a href="product/singleproductdetails.php?productId=<?php echo $featuredProduct['id'];?>">
        <?php
            foreach ($featuredProductImages as $featuredProductImage) {
        ?>
        <img class="slider" src="file/images/productimage/<?php echo $featuredProductImage['name']?>" alt="<?php echo $featuredProduct['name']; ?>">
        <?php
            break;
            } 
        ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

it is working totally fine. But problem is when try to go another page it gives me that error. In my same script file have more `js` function for those another page. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the output of your `var x` on another page ?

Comment: it shows nothing. I used `alert(x)` but it shows nothing. Even it is not showing anything `alert(x)` where slider is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This line has a problem

```
x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";  //***problem is here***
```

Because you are not handling the condition if `slideIndex` is `0`, then `x[-1]` will return `undefined`.

**Also you don't need to hide all the `slider`s every-time**, just remember the last `slider` which was displayed.

```
var slideIndex = -1;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slider");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)  //hide all of the one by one
{
  x[i].style.display = "none";
}

carousel();

function carousel() 
{
  if ( slideIndex >= 0 )
  {
     x[ slideIndex ].style.display = "none"; //hide last image
  }     
  if ( slideIndex >= (x.length - 1) ) 
  {
    slideIndex = -1; //make it -1 as index starts from 0
  }

  x[ ++slideIndex ].style.display = "block"; //show next image
  setTimeout(carousel, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
}
```

```js
var slideIndex = -1;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slider");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) //hide all of the one by one
{
  x[i].style.display = "none";
}

function slider() {
  if (slideIndex >= 0) {
    x[slideIndex].style.display = "none"; //hide last image
  }
  if (slideIndex >= (x.length - 1)) {
    slideIndex = -1; //make it -1 as index starts from 0
  }

  x[++slideIndex].style.display = "block"; //show next image
  setTimeout(slider, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  slider();
});
```

```html
<div class="slider-image">
  <img class="slider" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/64867-200.png">
  <img class="slider" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/112080-200.png">
  <img class="slider" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/115291-200.png">
  <img class="slider" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/116321-200.png">
  <img class="slider" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/116322-200.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Still same problem.  My slider is working fine. But when I want to move another page this slider script load and shows this error. How I can stop loading this function in another page. Maybe it will solve my problem.

Comment: @Fokrule What does *But when I want to move another page* mean? *How I can stop loading this function in another page* You simply need to not-call the carousel function.

Comment: Look. I have used `onload="slider()" ` in my `div` and changed function name to `slider()` . But it is still load another page. I have edited my queston.

Comment: @Fokrule It is hard to see **why not** without seeing the rest of code. It is possible that your *another page* also have a `slider` method which is overriding this method. Also, you need to change `setTimeout(carousel, 4000);` to `setTimeout(slider, 4000);` as well. Make sure that `slideIndex` is initialized properly before `slider` is invoked with the same code.

Comment: when I use onload function it loads the images for slider. I can see them in the page source . But it is not showing in the view page. So I have keep those script file in a difference script file and add that only on that page where slider needed.

Comment: @Fokrule It works fine in the demo I have attached. Please have a look.